# How to change the vertical alignment on thead row in html table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the vertical alignment on the header row of a table and am not having much luck. It seems stuck on the default vertical alignment of middle and I want it to be bottom aligned.

Part of the issue is that I want to format the header row in one way, and format the `th` elements in the first column a different way. I have tried adjusting the `vertical-align` property every which way and with every element. It seems that the `vertical-alignment` property works on `th` and `td` elements but not on `thead` elements. Am I missing something?

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A1</th>
      <td>Albert</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B2</th>
      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>C3</th>
      <td>Charlie</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[This is what I am expecting the output to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0WJh.png)

Comment: what do you mean with "want it to be bottom aligned" ??

Comment: By "bottom aligned" I mean that the when the table cell height is taller than the text that the text appears closer to the bottom of the cell. The default is that it is aligned in the center between top & bottom of the cell. The vertical-align property should adjust where in the cell the text appears but it is not working in the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {

  border: 2px solid blue;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

th {vertical-align: bottom;}
thead th {
  height: 100px;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A1</th>
      <td>Albert</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B2</th>
      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>C3</th>
      <td>Charlie</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi vadivel, so it looks like you moved the height from the 'thead' to the 'th' element, is that right? That works as far as getting the header row to now be aligned to the bottom but I still want the non-header rows to only be 50px high. Any way to do that as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share your expected screenshot?

Comment: Edited the original post to add an image

Comment: Can you check now